# How can I test a functional component method with React Developer Tools?

Tags: reactjs, debugging

With Class components you could use [React Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en), select the component in the `⚛️ Components` dev tools tab, and test any of its method using `$r.methodName()` in the console.

When I try the same with Functional components, I get `Uncaught TypeError: $r.methodName is not a function`.

Is there a way to test a functional component method from the browser console using React Dev Tools?